# Visual Studio cannot resolve symbols and yet builds. Cannot resolve symbol onmodelcreating

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, xaf

I can open and build EFDemoCodeFirst project from Dev Express 21.1.4
However visual studio shows that some symbols cannot be resolved.

Why does it build and run when VS2019 shows red?

[image: Red code]

Resharper 2020.3.2

Comment: Do you have any extensions e.g. ReSharper installed?

Comment: Yes I do. That must be the answer. Strangely the problem has disappeared now.

Comment: Yeah, happens to me occasionally with ReSharper, have to restart VS to get R# to figure things out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem goes away on installing Resharper 2021.2